# IBRS suffix of CPU models in QEMU

Tags: qemu, cpu-architecture

What is the difference between the IBRS suffix and no-suffix CPU models in QEMU?
Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU model with the -IBRS suffix has Spectre V2 (CVE-2017-5715) mitigation [turned on by default in the guest](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-cpu-models.html#important-cpu-features-for-intel-x86-hosts).

The CPU model *without* the suffix has the mitigation off by default.

Unless you have a specific, extremely compelling reason to *not* have this mitigation, you should always use the IBRS variant of the virtual CPU.

Comment: Does this fix have any kind of impact on performances?

Comment: @user2965433 There's the normal performance impact of Spectre mitigations. You can measure it if you really need to, but it should not be significant enough to bother.